# Change language of system and error messages in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to change the language of system messages from PostgreSQL?

In MSSQL for instance this is possible with the SQL statement [SET LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx).

Answer (score 52):

```
SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

More info on requirements and limitations [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-MESSAGES).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to have any effect when the database server is installed on Windows.

Comment: According to this bug report - http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2008-05/msg00134.php, you're right. Have you tried to change the 'lc_messages' setting directly in the postgresql.conf and to restart?

Comment: Now, after reading the mentioned thread in the archives, the only way to change the language of the system messages seems to be to change the OS locale.

Comment: Appears to have been fixed. Command now works on Windows (Server 2008 R2, PostgreSQL 9.0.3)

Comment: Note that "Only superusers can change this setting", so it may be worth reminding one can log as superuser e.g. with `sudo -u postgres psql`.

Comment: This might not work for some installations as `en_US.UTF-8` locale might not be available. Safer solution is to use `SET lc_messages TO 'C';` (which also means English). Use `locale -l` in shell to test for available locale.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make it permanent to me on PostgreSQL 9.4, I had to change this setting in the postgresql.conf

Comment: Just want to add that Postgres should be built with NLS support.

Answer (score 46):

For me neither Milen A. Radev's nor user1's answer worked - editing `PostgreSQL\11\data\postgresql.conf` had absolutely no effect. Even after setting `lc_messages = 'random value'` PostgreSQL would still start.

What helped was to delete `PostgreSQL\11\share\locale\*\LC_MESSAGES`, after that I finally got English messages.

Comment: This helped me. I deleted the entrie LC_MESSAGES folder and i got english messages.

Comment: PGSQL 11 / Win 10 x64, I had to reload the server configuration and then it worked. Thanks

Comment: I had to rename locale folder to locale_ and restart postgres, then it worked, thanks. Nothing else worked for me neither.

Comment: Just delete or rename the `locale` folder, and it worked like a charm!

Comment: The only solution that worked for me on Windows. Crazy. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

Milen's answer didn't work for me.

I got it working by modifying a file `postgresql.conf`. If you're on Linux, write:

```
sudo find / -iname postgresql.conf
```

I had mine in `/var/lib/pgsql/data`.
Then edit the file and search for a variable `lc_messages` and change it to your preferred language, e.g. `'en_US.UTF-8'`.

If PostgreSQL stops working and you check in its log that you have an error that looks like this:

```
invalid value for parameter "lc_messages": "en_US.UTF-8"
```

You have to edit `/etc/locale.gen` and uncomment line with encoding from the error message (e.g. `en_US.UTF-8`). Then you have to run `locale-gen` (as root) to update the locales. Finally, to check if the locale is set you can run `locale -a`.

Or, if you want the language to be English, you can just set `lc_messages = 'C'`.

Comment: Mine was in `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` on an Ubuntu 14.04 with postgresql installed from the official PostgreSQL PPA. Leaving it here for the benefit of others.

Comment: On `windows` e.g. `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data`

Comment: `lc_messages = 'C'` works great :-). Seems like most universal (working on Windows and Linux).

Answer (score 9):

In my case (on Windows Server 2019) I managed to change language by creating a system environment variable "LC_MESSAGES" with value "English":

```
setx LC_MESSAGES English /m
```

(Solution taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31605952/1961209))

Comment: I tried this solution first since it was fast and easy to verify. I can say it worked and I didn't need to try the other solutions. I'm working on Windows 10.

Comment: Worked for me too; Windows 11

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced the same issue with naming of `PostgreSQL` error messages which were specifically displayed in `Intellij IDEA` similar to:

[image]

the only solution for me was [renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191428/change-language-of-system-and-error-messages-in-postgresql#comment121662022_56811670) `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\share\locale` folder to another default name.

then as result changed to:

[image]

**To be noticed:** it wasn't related to `Intellij Idea` configurations at all, because I tested different answers (and other non-related to `IDE` answers), e.g., like:

1. [Help | Edit custom VM options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007648019-Hot-to-change-error-messages-to-English-Intellij-)
2. [Setting of Environments variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59288926/8370915)
3. [Using specific commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191958/8370915)

Answer (score 1):

I simply deleted the LC_MESSAGE folder from

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\share\locale\<LANGUAGE YOU WANT TO GET RID OF>\LC_MESSAGE
```

and re-log in to psql

Answer (score 0):

only change postgresql.conf is not working on windows10，the following method is fine for me，is very simple but work:

1. change lc_message = en_US.UTF-8, in postgresql.conf;
2. delete all files in fold: \share\locale, expect es fold or the
   language you want to keep;
3. restart pg service and then you will find that is what you want!