# postgresql as an embedded Database

Tags: postgresql, embedded-database

Need a small help regarding the embedded version of PostgreSql. I see that we can create an embedded form of PostgreSql https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-database-spring-test . But the page specifies mostly a test oriented library and it does not specify if this can be used in a production environment. The requirement is to store some JSON data that will be too large for memory and having a full fledged DB will be too slow. It is good to have a DB spun up for the duration of the function and kill it once the function is complete. So having an embedded version of DB seemed like a good trade off. PostgreSql also provides native JSON handling which provides a lot of advantages if it can be used. I also see that there is no official embedded version of postgresql. Can this be used in the production environment?

Comment: Don't do it. Postgres is not intended as an embedded databases (and probably never will be). You will have a lot of trouble getting this to work properly (in a robust way). Use a dedicated JSON/Document database that can be embedded instead. But Postgres **is** "a full fledged DB" and you yourself claim that it "will be too slow". So why try this at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74220718/3492996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't.

If you need an embedded DB for a short duration I would recommend taking a look at `sqlite` (which supports json, but I don't know if it fits your requirements), or `h2` using a file as the backing mechanism. You could also take a look at RocksDB, but that is a lot lower level.

Sqlite and RocksDb are used by many products. I'm sure h2 is used here and there but probably to a far lower extent.

You'll also need to think about the storage of your service to find out if the IOPS are good enough (running on mechanical drives will be very different from nvme).

Answer (score 1):

the best embedded db as far as i know is firebird and it is really robust