# Change language of the PostgreSQL server error messages to English

Tags: postgresql

My MS Windows system is French version. I've recently installed PostgreSQL server. Although pgAdmin is in English I get French messages in the PostgreSQL psql command line.

Answer (score 23):

If you have permissions for access to `$datadir\postgresql.conf` change `lc_messages` parameter to `English_United States.1252`. You need to reload configuration (do restart of the server).

My config is:

```
# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252'  # locale for system error message

# strings
lc_monetary = 'English_United States.1252'  # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'English_United States.1252'   # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'English_United States.1252'      # locale for time formatting

# default configuration for text search
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me, thanks. The "environment variable" mentioned in the other post didn't work. In case anybody else is wondering: in my case, the `postgresql.conf` file was located under `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data\postgresql.conf`.

Comment: On Windows you have to restart the PostgreSQL service for the change to take effect. Find it among other services in [Windows Services Manager](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/ways-access-services-windows/), right-click it and select `restart`. Wait it restarts and check the result.

Comment: `English_United Kingdom.1252` for those want to change it to UK English.

Answer (score 17):

You need to [define an environment variable](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/create-custom-environment-variables-in-windows-7/) named `LC_MESSAGES`and set that to `English`

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this through my application's settings to have control over these messages in an application? I am using Delphi with FireDAC data access components.

Answer (score 2):

You can define `LC_MESSAGES` MS Windows environment variable or configure your `postgresql.conf` file. If they will be set both for different values, `postgresql.conf` will take the place. Look into docu [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/locale.html) and [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT).