# Setting error messages to English not working

Tags: postgresql

For some reason I cannot change the language of the error messages from PostgreSQL. I have tried to set the language inside the script for creating the schema in at the first line:

```
SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

and I also did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605837/change-postgres-error-messages-language-to-english), setting `LC_MESSAGES` to `English` but it didn't help. Yes, I restarted the service after changing the value.

[image]

Nothing seems to work. I am still getting my messages in German.

What else can I *try*?

Comment: Apparently some users have had issues when using `SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';` did you try running this command as admin/sudo?

Comment: @Haymaker Yes, I think so. I am running the script out of my Eclipse which runs in admin mode. That shouldn't be the problem I guess.

Comment: I would say try running postgres from terminal as administrator and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Check that LANGUAGE environment variable is not set when you start your PostgreSQL server. Its value overrides any locale settings.

Comment: @EgorRogov I don't see a variable LANGUAGE under my environment variables.

Comment: I have `lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252'` in my `postgresql.conf`  and that works just fine (together with the env var - not sure if I need both)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually I don't have that file in `PostgreSQL\9.4\data`. I didn't change anything there. It's a clean installation.

Comment: You can't start Postgres without it. You can get the path of the file  being used through: `select setting from pg_settings where name = 'config_file'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Since this was the issue there's a bounty worth 50 reputation waiting for you. The file was located on a different drive ..

Comment: BTW, the simplest setting to get original English error messages is `SET lc_messages = 'C'`. Effectively not using a locale, this works universally.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Are you going to provide the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have permission for access to $datadir\postgresql.conf, you change lc_messages parameter to 'English_United States.1252'.

After you must reload configuration.

My config settings is here;

> #These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
>
> lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252'            # locale for system error message strings
>
> lc_monetary = 'English_United States.1252'         # locale for monetary formatting
>
> lc_numeric = 'English_United States.1252'          # locale for number formatting
>
> lc_time = 'English_United States.1252'             # locale for time formatting
>
> # default configuration for text search
>
> default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following command?

```
initdb --locale=en_US --lc_messages=en_US
```

for details, please refer to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/locale.html