# How to change display language in psql shell?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

[tried using SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8'; seems not working for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAAFT.png)

Here is a picture showing what it looks like:

[image]

My system language is English, I set locale to English when I install Postgres.

Not sure what happened.

I've googled around can't find anything relevant

Is there any way I can change it to English?

Thank you！

Answer (score -1):

`SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';` try running it, Hoping it would solve the Problem.

There's another Stack Question regarding the same Problem, Kindly Check this Link Out : [Change language of system and error messages in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191428/change-language-of-system-and-error-messages-in-postgresql)

Comment: Thank you but I tried it, and it seems not working. I added a picture to the first line of the question showing what I did

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56811670/10096675 This works for me. What I did is delete zh_CN and zh_TW folders. but I back it up somewhere else just in case I need it sometime in the future :)

Comment: Kindly Upvote the Answer Which worked for you, So others can get maximum benefit from it too.